# Return statement with [..._items]

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not able to understand the return statement in the code provided down below.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:GreatPlace/models/place.dart';

class GreatPlaces with ChangeNotifier{

List<Place> _items=[];
List<Place> get item{
  return[..._items];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'...' is the spread operator. In your example, [] creates a List object and ..._items inserts all objects from _items into that list.

So basically item returns a list with the same values as _items.

Refer to this article for an example of the spread operator and other Dart 2.3 features:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d'

This operator makes sense if you want to create a list that combines other lists or adds extra values.

Example:

```
List<String> items1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
List<String> items2 = ['d','e','f'];
List<String> items3 = [...items1, ...items2, '!'];

print(items3);
//[a, b, c, d, e, f, !]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, it's called `Spreading Operator`. Please see the below code, if you want to concatenate two arrays.

```
List<int> _itemsOne = [1, 2, 3];
List<int> _itemsTwo = [4, 5, 6];
final _itemsAll = [..._itemsOne, ..._itemsTwo];
print(_itemsAll); // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

You can ask why not use `List` method `addAll`. Let's say one of your `List` is `null` and if you add another `List`, it'll crash.

```
List<int> _itemsOne;
List<int> _itemsTwo = [4, 5, 6];
_itemsOne?.addAll(_itemsTwo);
```

But in spreading operator, if you expect the array `null`, you can use null safe operator `?` in front of it.

```
List<int> _itemsOne;
List<int> _itemsTwo = [4, 5, 6];
final _itemsAll = [...?_itemsOne, ..._itemsTwo];
print(_itemsAll); // prints [4, 5, 6]
```